# Wordpress Buddypress registration plugin activation link not working

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I have installed wordpress buddypress registration plugin. When I register I am getting account activation link as below

http://www.exampl.com/activity/07403d41406825bb3c3a70d415899491/

when I click on this link I am getting page not found error.

you can help to solve this issue

Comment: do you have another registration in the site?

Comment: no i have one registration only using buddypress plugin only

Answer (score 1):

I have found answer myself for my above question.

I have made lot of research and found that it is required to create page and assign that page in buddypress page setting in activate select box.

after that it will working fine and activate user successfully as expected.